# Non-breaking space in reference title

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Inserting a tilde (~) in a .bib reference title prints the tilde instead of creating a non-breaking space. Is there a way of adding non-breaking spaces to reference titles? I tried {~}, but it also just prints a tilde. I'm using Mendeley and BibTex.

Comment: what gets put in the generated bib file? presumably not `~` if it appears in the output as `~` ?

Comment: I just checked, and $\sim$ gets generated in the bib file. Is there anyway to force a tilde to remain as a tilde during generation of the bib file?

Comment: @CedricEveleigh that's a mendeley question not a tex or bibtex one and I can't help there have never used it.

Comment: if you can't configure mendeley for ~ you can use `\nobreakspace` which is the same thing,

Comment: When I try adding \nobreakspace followed by a space in a reference title, it gives me an undefined control sequence error and produces no space at all. In this case, the \nobreakspace is being passed on correctly in the bib file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It turns out that I had to clean my auxiliary files - latex was going a little bonkers - and \nobreakspace worked. Thanks. :) You can add your comment as a answer and I'll mark this off as answered, or I can add the answer myself if you'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't configure mendeley for `~` you can use `\nobreakspace` which is the same thing.